# Caching in microservices architecture Nestjs + Apollo federation

Tags: caching, graphql, microservices, nestjs, apollo-federation

I am looking for a way to implement caching in Nestjs + graphql. I have distributed my services with apollo federations, Hence using microservices architecture.

I want, if anything inside graphql query, headers, params will change then it should fetch the new data otherwise fetch data from cache.

Read Nest js & graphql documentations, Tried reading multiple articles but wasn't able to find How to implement above.

Can anyone please help with the same?